# Assertion Error in Kalman Filter python OpenCV 2.4.0

Tags: python, opencv, assertion, kalman-filter

When I try to predict Kalman,

```
k = cv2.KalmanFilter(2,1,0)
c = np.array([(0.0),(0.0)]).reshape(2,1)
a = k.predict(c)
```

I am getting following Assertion Error.

> error:
>   /home/jay/Downloads/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp:711:
>   error: (-215) type == B.type() && (type == CV_32FC1 || type ==
>   CV_64FC1 || type == CV_32FC2 || type == CV_64FC2) in function gemm

So, I added following line of code in `OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp`

```
printf("%d %d\n",type,B.type());
```

So, now it gives me output as,

> 5 5
>
> 0 6

Am I doing something wrong here ? What's the problem ?